# PostGIS doesn't work after update in Manjaro

Tags: postgresql, postgis, proj

I recently ran a full update on my Manjaro-System, afterwards, when I tried to run a small script I use to start and automatically save my Postgres-DB I get the following error in the shell.

> pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  could not load library
> "/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so:
> undefined symbol: list_make1_impl

pg_dump: error: query was:

```
SELECT
a.attnum,
a.attname,
a.atttypmod,
a.attstattarget,
a.attstorage,
t.typstorage,
a.attnotnull,
a.atthasdef,
a.attisdropped,
a.attlen,
a.attalign,
a.attislocal,
pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, a.atttypmod) AS atttypname,
a.attgenerated,
CASE WHEN a.atthasmissing AND NOT a.attisdropped THEN a.attmissingval ELSE null END AS attmissingval,
a.attidentity,
pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(option_name) || ' ' || pg_catalog.quote_literal(option_value) FROM pg_catalog.pg_options_to_table(attfdwoptions) ORDER BY option_name), E',
    ') AS attfdwoptions,
CASE WHEN a.attcollation <> t.typcollation THEN a.attcollation ELSE 0 END AS attcollation,
array_to_string(a.attoptions, ', ') AS attoptions
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
WHERE a.attrelid = '18597'::pg_catalog.oid AND a.attnum > 0::pg_catalog.int2
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Also, when I start the database in pgAdmin I can open all the tables except the one which holds the *geography*-column, which needs PostGIS. It shows me the following error instead:

> ERROR:  could not load library /usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so: /usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-3.so: undefined symbol: list_make1_impl    SQL state: 58P01

Apparently something in the *proj*-package is messed up. According to [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393491/postgis-layer-not-available-after-update/393504#393504), it could have something to do with this package being installed several times. However, I reinstalled *proj* manually, from the Official Repo as well as from the AUR each time with a different version and cleaned the old version every time. The error is still there.

Currently the version setup is:

```
QGIS: Version 3.16.5
Postgres: Version 12.6-1
PostGIS: Version 3.0.3-1
proj: Version 6.3.2-1
Manjaro: KDE-Plasma 5.21.3
Kernel: 4.19.183-1-Manjaro
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the local Linux User Group I found a solution to the problem. It turned out, that PostGIS was updated in the background and the new version did not correspond with PostgreSQL 12.6 any more. Since PostGIS was already installed, it did not show me this but the error message above instead.

To check if PostGIS is still compatible with PostgreSQL, I create a new database and then tried to add the PostGIS extension. I got the following message, that cleared things up:

```
test=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/extensionpost.control": No such file or directory
test=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR: PostGIS built for PostgreSQL 13.0 cannot be loaded in PostgreSQL 12.6
```

So I updated PostgreSQL, set up a new database cluster and used `pg_restore` on the last .sql from my automatic `pg_dump` to recreate the database. It now works as before again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try downgrading Postgis to the previous version. First, check the files at `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/postgis-*` to see available versions.

Then, use Pacman to downgrade to a version of choice, for example:

```
sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/postgis-3.3.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

This also works to fix upgrade troubles with Postgres itself.

To make sure that Manjaro doesn't mess up the versions on its own in the future, edit the `IgnorePkg` line in `/etc/pacman.conf` to block automatic postgres updates (extend the line if you already specified some packages there).

```
IgnorePkg = postgresql postgis
```